# SQL: Unnest array keeping the same number of rows in aws athena

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto, unnest

Base from the following query

```
SELECT internal_transaction_id, tags FROM "bankstatements"."statements_transactions_sample_data"
```

I get the below table

```
+-----------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| internal_transaction_id     | tags                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   |
+-----------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2173059                     | [{category=null, creditdebit=credit, lendertype=null, pending=null, pre_authorisation=null, thirdparty=null}, {category=null, creditdebit=null, lendertype=null, pending=null, pre_authorisation=null, thirdparty=Internal Transfer Credit}, {category=Internal Transfer, creditdebit=null, lendertype=null, pending=null, pre_authorisation=null, thirdparty=null}]
+-----------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2173061                     | [{category=null, creditdebit=credit, lendertype=null, pending=null, pre_authorisation=null, thirdparty=null}, {category=null, creditdebit=null, lendertype=null, pending=null, pre_authorisation=null, thirdparty=UBER}, {category=External Transfer, creditdebit=null, lendertype=null, pending=null, pre_authorisation=null, thirdparty=null}]
+-----------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I want to unnest the column "tags" keeping the same number of rows. Currently my query

```
SELECT 
internal_transaction_id, t.category, t.creditdebit, t.lendertype, t.pending, t.pre_authorisation, t.thirdparty
FROM 
"bankstatements"."statements_transactions_sample_data"
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(tags) AS tag (t)
```

Have as an out come:

```
+-----------------------------+---------------------+---------------+---------------+-----------+-----------------------+---------------------------+
| internal_transaction_id     | category            | creditdebit   | lendertype    | pending   | pre_authorisation     | thirdparty                |
+-----------------------------+---------------------+---------------+---------------+-----------+-----------------------+---------------------------+
| 2173059                     |                     | credit        |               |           |                       |                           |
+-----------------------------+---------------------+---------------+---------------+-----------+-----------------------+---------------------------+
| 2173059                     |                     |               |               |           |                       | Internal Transfer Credit  |
+-----------------------------+---------------------+---------------+---------------+-----------+-----------------------+---------------------------+
| 2173059                     | Internal Transfer   |               |               |           |                       |                           |
+-----------------------------+---------------------+---------------+---------------+-----------+-----------------------+---------------------------+
| 2173061                     |                     | credit        |               |           |                       |                           |
+-----------------------------+---------------------+---------------+---------------+-----------+-----------------------+---------------------------+
| 2173061                     |                     |               |               |           |                       | UBER                      |
+-----------------------------+---------------------+---------------+---------------+-----------+-----------------------+---------------------------+
| 2173061                     | External Transfer   |               |               |           |                       |                           |
+-----------------------------+---------------------+---------------+---------------+-----------+-----------------------+---------------------------+
```

I am wodnering how can I unnest the tags to have only 2 rows like the following:

```
+-----------------------------+---------------------+---------------+---------------+-----------+-----------------------+---------------------------+
| internal_transaction_id     | category            | creditdebit   | lendertype    | pending   | pre_authorisation     | thirdparty                |
+-----------------------------+---------------------+---------------+---------------+-----------+-----------------------+---------------------------+
| 2173059                     | Internal Transfer   | credit        |               |           |                       | Internal Transfer Credit  |
+-----------------------------+---------------------+---------------+---------------+-----------+-----------------------+---------------------------+
| 2173061                     | External Transfer   |               |               |           |                       | UBER                      |
+-----------------------------+---------------------+---------------+---------------+-----------+-----------------------+---------------------------+
```

The tags tag in the JSON looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "thirdParty": "Other Credits"
    },
    {
        "category": "All Other Credits"
    },
    {
        "creditDebit": "credit"
    }
]
```

When I define the create:

```
tags: array<
    struct<
        category: string,
        creditdebit: string,
        lendertype: string,
        pending: string,
        pre_authorisation: string,
        thirdparty: string                                            
    >
>
```

Comment: What is the datatype of the tags column?

Comment: @OluwafemiSule I have edited the question and add the infromation at the end

Comment: Do a group by _internal_transaction_id_ with MAX function on the columns

Comment: @Guy That worked, I was thinking in grouping but didnt thought MAX will do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

aggregate using min or max:

```
SELECT 
internal_transaction_id, max(t.category) as category, max(t.creditdebit) as creditdebit, max(t.lendertype) as lendertype, max(t.pending) as pending, max(t.pre_authorisation) as pre_authorisation, max(t.thirdparty) as thirdparty
FROM 
"bankstatements"."statements_transactions_sample_data"
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(tags) AS tag (t) 
GROUP BY internal_transaction_id
```